# build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I cannot seem to be able to archive an app on a new computer.  I created new provisioning profiles for distribution and development.  I created a new Certificate Signing Request.  I can build my app on my iPhone, but I cannot archive it.  I keep getting the error:

> No matching provisioning profiles found Your build settings specify a
>   provisioning profile with the UUID “BD657D9A-...”, however, no such
>   provisioning profile was found.  Xcode can resolve this issue by
>   downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

I tried clicking on "Fix Issue" and it still continues to be an error.  I removed my certificates from the keychain and downloaded it again through the development portal and that didn't work.  I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, closing Xcode, and those all do not work either.  I have tried to do different combinations of Code Signing-> Automatic, as well as choosing my debug provisioning profile to be my development profile I just created in the dev portal, and manually choosing the distribution profile I just created in the dev portal as well.  Both do not seem to work.  Any other troubleshooting tips?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you change the deployment target from simulator to the device? If that doesn't work, I sometimes have to download the provisioning profile manually too and open it in Xcode.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Yes it is set to build for device, but still no dice.

Answer (score 114):

I'm using XCode 7.2 and saw this problem. Restarting XCode solved this for me. Not sure it will always solve the problem, but you may want to try this first.

Comment: This fixed it after 30 mins of troubleshooting, thanks. So frustrating.

Comment: Thank you so much. I spend 2 hours

Comment: Worked for me too.  I'd already restarted Xcode many times for other issues this evening but somehow took me until I found this post to try it for this issue... I really hate Apple for this.

Comment: I could not up vote you twice otherwise would give 100+

Comment: Restarted and cleaned the project. Worked :)

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you

Comment: As late as XCode 7.3 -- yup, just needed a restart.

Comment: I updated Xcode to 7.3.1 for no reason, but what finally works is a restart. Phew!

Answer (score 42):

I know its too late to put an answer here but this question comes up at the top after searching this issue. I managed to solve this by selecting the project and in `Build settings` changed the `UUID` options to what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have installed the certificates and provisioning files on your MAC

Comment: Just an fyi, I was stuck on this for a while and it's worth pointing out that you need to make sure you have "target" selected when making these changes and not "project".  This is found to the left of the tabs at the top of the screen under the name of your project (in the screen shot above it's "N...") -- you're on the wrong screen if you only see "Info" and "Build Settings"

Answer (score 17):

If you are now using Xcode 7.2, it appears you will receive this message if you download individual profiles either from the Developer Center or from Xcode > Preferences > Account. Select Team Name and View Details > Provisioning Profiles section. I downloaded individual profiles (I've got several dozen so its hard to find a particular one) and was running into this error. Even if you select Download All after downloading individual profiles, this error still comes up.

You will need to find the Provisioning Profiles and delete them then select Download All. Easiest way is to right click on a profile in an Account's details that is already downloaded and select Show In Finder and delete them all. Then just select Download All and hopefully your profiles will match up to your Code Signing.

See: [Xcode 7.2 no matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found)

Comment: This got rid of OP's error for me, but now I get 'A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found'. What a frustrating error

Comment: I just found that you can get to the profiles quickly from Xcode by right-clicking on them and selecting "Reveal in Finder" in the "Select Team Name and View Details > Provisioning Profiles" section.

Comment: I done exactly as @adamteale done and it fixed it for me. XCode seems to be getting worse at this somehow...

Comment: This was the real fix. I said "show in finder" and then deleted every single profile on my local machine. Then I said "download all" and we're good to go.

Comment: Doing 'download all' fixed a similar problem for me; just downloading the profiles I was using (and deleting and re-downloading them, and then deleting and restarting and downloading again) didn't fix it.

Comment: Worked for me; have a plus

Comment: Oh god!! After all the code issues you have to deal with these irritating errors too now a days

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue with Xcode 7.2 and an example I downloaded from a tutorial site, and I tried to run this on my iPhone.

For me this simple solution worked :

1) under 'Build settings' -> 'Code signing' : you'll find the 'hard coded' UUID of the original creator -> change this to 'automatic' for both the debug and release:

[image]

2) under 'General' -> 'Identity' -> Team : select your provisioning profile. You can also update the bundle identifier if needed.

[image]

3) a 'clean' is always a good idea after such changes, then build

this solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue of Xcode 7.1. In my case, recreating the profile was the only successful workaround

1. Delete the previous distribution profile at the Member Centre
2. Recreate the distribution profile
3. Archive with the recreated profile

Comment: I still can't get this to work...any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the DerivedData for the project worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility) and XCode organizer to ensure all certificates/provisions are configured correctly (they should be marked as green ones). Please check if your device is included into certificate/provision on Apple Developer.

Such verifying and killing/opening XCode (kill it totally, in use of Activity Monitor) worked for me

Comment: The iPhone Configuration Utility is not available in every country's app store it would seem.. :-|

Answer (score 1):

I updated Xcode7.1 to 7.1.1. Then, solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when i tried to archive, tried re-starting XCode, cleaning, rebuilding, nothing worked for a while. Then with the target selected as my project, under General -> Identity -> Bundle identifier, I just deleted and then re-typed the same exact (i know it's silly!) bundle identifier name and then tried to archive again, this time it worked. Such a crazy bug.

Comment: Flagged as 'not an answer'?

Answer (score 1):

I opened project.pbxproj with text editor and searched for UUID and delete the line like this PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "UUID";

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue… Make sure the BUNDLE IDENTIFIER in Xcodeʻs GENERAL view for your project matches what the profile reads on your Dev web portal, and then THAT profile is installed in Xcode verbatim. Select that profile in your BUILD setting, and you could be solved by now (the App installed on devices without issue), but we also noticed we could to go back to GENERAL view and the FIX button actually worked: it fixed the "not found" profile (once "fixed" the fix button disappears)

Comment: What is General View.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are copying the profiles manually from their "Provisioning Profiles" folder in "~/Library/MobileDevice" with success (including myself).  If this works for you, quit copy+pasting and symlink it!

`$ sudo -i`

`# mkdir /Library/MobileDevice; ln -s /Users/myuser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ /Library/MobileDevice/` -- where **myuser** is your username.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your bundle id matches app id in developer portal. I had bundle id `com.company.MyApp` and app id `com.company.myapp`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by the following steps:

1. cd ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
2. rm *.mobileprovision
3. reset your provision

Answer (score 0):

Given up on all of the above. The only thing that worked for me was:

1. Delete certs and profiles from developer portal
2. Delete certs and profiles from mac
3. Recreate certs and profiles in developer portal, download and install on mac
4. Delete bundle identifier from 'General' tab in xcode
5. Re-add bundle identifier
6. Assign new profiles and code signing entities (dev and prod) in xcode code signing
7. (clean again), build, deploy to device/simulator as a test
8. Archive and upload to itunes current version

On step 7, xcode requested access to keychain (which it did not do in other solutions stated above), once granted - it worked.

Same for step 8.

Not sure what was going on (my certs and profiles were only 3 months old), and I admit this was a 'brute force' method - but it worked.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything that everyone suggested, but none of these fixed my issue.

Using Xcode 7.3.1, what did fix it was this:

Change the settings to run the app on the simulator.  If you have it set to run on a device, and the device udid isn't in the provisioning profile, it will (wrongly) yell at you.

Go to your Project > Target > Build settings > Code Signing > Provisioning profile and change it from "Automatic" to select the exact profile you want.  At this point, if you haven't changed the app to run on a simulator, an alert might pop up yelling at you to "Fix Issue".  DON'T do that!

After you manually select your provisioning profile from the list, archive your app.  Viola!

Answer (score -1):

Most of you will face this issue in latest version of XCode i.e. 7.1, so the solution I used to solve this is

1. Complile the code in Xcode 7.0
2. Clean the Project
3. Build the Project
4. Archive

All Done.