# No matching provision profile found Xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm getting the following error:

> Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID
>   XXX-XXX-XX..., however, no such provisioning profile was found.

I allredy tried to delete my provision profiles from Xcode and redownload them like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found) answer, but it didn't help. When I go to *~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/* I can actually see the provision profile that Xcode is telling me that doesn't exists. I also tried restarting Xcode, and it didn't help either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to fix this, as per how Apple tech support advises is:

```
1) (not advised by apple as you should have an ID). But Ensure that your DeveloperID is added to Xcode. (If it's an ID that hasn't got Agent or Admin access) then you need to make sure the you've created the correct provisioning profiles and installed them. If it is an Admin/Agent account, all's good

2) Open the project in question and:
    i) Click on the target which you're having problems with
    ii) Click on the "General" tab
    iii) Make sure that the "Signing" is set to "None"
    iv) Click on the "Build Settings" tab
    v) Make sure that "All" and "Combined" levels are chosen" (see the image below, All and Combined levels are just under the main tabs on the left)
```

[image]

```
   vi) Scroll down to "Code Signing"
   vii) You only need to worry about the "Code signing identity". If that's filled in, click on the line and press backspace (delete) so it clears it
   viii) The resource rules should be empty as this no longer applies (for general purpose use)
   ix) Under Provisioning Profile, change it to "Automatic"
```

After this press:

```
1) Cmd + Shift + K to do a build clean 
2) after this is done, press Cmd + B to build
```

If this doesn't pan out, then head back over to the "General Tab" and under the "Siging" section as mentioned in (2 iii) above, you'll see a "Fix Problems" button...

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

A

Comment: Does not work.   CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 9.3'