# how to fix importing certificate issue

Tags: ios, xcode

That the error xcode appear:

> Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “some_number”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.

I had already tried that solution:

[Xcode 7.2 no matching provisioning profiles found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found)

I'm trying to upload an App from a not mine account.

I've imported the profile to Xcode. 
He send me the .mobileprovision for distribution.

But when I try to archive I get the above error. 
How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All **provisioning profile** are signed with a Key/Certificate Pair.

You can ask the owner of the account to export the Certificate with it's key in a P12 format using **Keychain Access** and then import it to your machine.

Other solution is to generate a Certificate for your use within the account where the App is registered.

Comment: what means import it to your machine?

Comment: When you receive the .p12 file you double-click it. It will be imported and installed in your keychain

Comment: E6ABB8A6D......13DA99: no identity found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1. What  is going on?

Comment: Did you import the .p12 file?

Comment: Now you should go to your build settings and point to the newly imported profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103604/discussion-between-ppaulojr-and-sarita).