# iOS provisioning is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

[image]

My provisioning certificates had expired after six months.

I have reactivated it by navigating to Provision Profiles --> Distribution --> Then I clicked on all expired profiles-->marked the radio button and renewed the provision certificate...so now all provision certificates is active...

But the problem is that even after renewal, Im unable to download the app in real devices and also Im unable to run the app project in my device.

When Im trying to run it on real device, `Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX”, however, no such provisioning profile was found.` is the error being thrown.

1. How can i  let my app to be downloaded sorting the issue?
2. How can I solve the build settings error and run my project in real device?

Answer (score 0):

do the following steps for fix this issue

Open Xcode preference  -->  Select  team -->  `View Details` -->

- `Signing Identities`  click on `Reset` for each of them.
- `Provisioning Profiles`. Click on `Download All`.
- Click  **Done**.

then  Go in Xcode, build settings, select it. In General tab, the issues should get removed.

finally Restart your Xcode. clean and build

**Update**

see the sample output

[image]

Comment: In section `Signing Identities` , `Reset` button is un available. There is only `create` button

Comment: I have of course downloaded all provisioning profiles already

Comment: see the link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found

Comment: I have posted the screen shot of my system

Comment: ok on your keychain check once the certificate is valid or not

Comment: In the certificate section of keychain, no certificates are available bro

Comment: ok then do like , go to your developer portal , re generate your certificates and try surely works

Comment: There is a certificate over there which says 'The certificate has expired'

Comment: in where developer portal or keychain, simple , revoke your old certificate and regenerate again then download and installl surely works

Comment: still the same problem is persisting

Comment: in my developer portal, all profiles are being shown as active but still the app is not being installed

Comment: apart from no other steps bro,

Answer (score 0):

You should create `new provisioning profile` and add them to the project i think just updating them would not solve this.