# Can I publish app on iTunes Remote without iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to push my app to iTunes Remote, and I am stuck at the point where I created my provisioning profile on iTunes Remote, downloaded the signed certificate and now I am configuring XCode. I am getting "No matching provisioning profiles found", after trying to "Fix issue" I get "No devices" error ("Creating a profile requires having a device registered in the Member Center.").

However, I don't have an iOS device. I only have my Mac. Can I still somehow publish the app?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can, you need a distribution profile. When you have one select iOS Device on Xcode then go to `Product > Archive`. It should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I made both distribution and development profiles. However, when I try to Archive the app with Generic iOS device set I get Build failed error due to "No matching provisioning profiles found...".

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34346436/2305521) SO question.

Comment: Unfortunately, tried it multiple times before posting here :( But I'll try to remove my Apple ID and try to remove/add new certificate, maybe that will work.

Comment: Does your app support iOS or this is an Mac application? Well You can upload it. You don't need any device but would you like to upload it without testing on device? Few bugs/crashes come on real device. You don't face them on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can publish your application on appStore without ios device.
Just select generic device from the simulator menu 
After that archive it and bingo upload section will open. Press upload select some details which is related to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've already tried that. Even with generic device selected I still get "No matching provisioning profiles found" error.

Comment: You have to download your distribution and development certificate from member center for special this application and also you have to use same account for it

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The problem was: In `Build Settings`, `Code Signing` section my Provisioning Profile row was set to "Automatic". Manually choosing my provisioning profile let me archive the product.