# "No provisioning profiles found" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

When I create an iOS project on my own, I can build it without any problem. I downloaded a project for testing purposes and now I get:

```
No provisioning profiles found
No non-expired provisioning profiles were found
```

In this case I downloaded an Xcode project from one of Apples tutorial pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7.2 no matching provisioning profiles found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found)

Comment: @nepa   Check my answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some cases that error can be caused by "Generic iOS Device" being selected as active scheme.

[image: Screenshot of active scheme selection]

Changing that to a specific device solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

Change your build setting for Code **Signing Identity** and **Provisioning Profile** first both in project and target...

Check image below ...

[image]

Change your Team from **General** tab...

Check image below ...

[image]

i hope this will help you...

Comment: I did this and it wasn't working, but then I noticed that there was "Generic iOS Device" selected as scheme I changed it to iOS 6. Does it make sense to integrate that in your answer?