# Xcode - Failed to create provisioning profile - without device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I run Mojave OS on VirtualBox (Windows) to develop React Native App. 
When I try build app in Xcode v10.3 to submit to Testflight, AppStore, etc.

## Steps:

- 1) Devices:

[image]

- 2) Build

[image]

I've next error:

[image]

the problem? I haven't a iOS device to register. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

- **You need a valid development team created** (in you Apple Project Account) and set in `Xcode->YourProjectTarget->Signing Capabilities.`
- **You also have to create Production certificate** to be able to generate a production archive.

For the profiles error you can check this link: ["No provisioning profiles found" in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969772/no-provisioning-profiles-found-in-xcode)

**NOTE:** after creating new profiles/certificates in `developer.apple.com` you can download/sync them in:
`Xcode --> Preferences --> Accounts`:

[image]

Comment: I have same problem in Flutter, I have a paid apple dev account, in xcode I select any IOS device, when I click archive I get the error: Failed to create provisioning profile