# No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the UUID “fbbe2..”, however, no such

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, xcode7.2

I am using **Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)** , when i am running my application on device OR generating **Development build OR Production build .IPA** i am getting following error

> No matching provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a
>   provisioning profile with the UUID
>   “fbbe2367-****-****-****-989e92b2****”, however, no such provisioning
>   profile was found.

I found one of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123682/build-settings-specify-a-provisioning-profile-with-the-uuid) very closed with me, I followed all the steps like Restarting XCode & so on, but no luck .

I clicked **Fix issue** many times as shown in screen but still same .

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: see this answer it helpes you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123682/build-settings-specify-a-provisioning-profile-with-the-uuid

Comment: Hi anbu , followed all process as suggested but no luck .

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346436/xcode-7-2-no-matching-provisioning-profiles-found

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Change provisioning profile to automatic in app build settings, it will let Xcode decide which provisioning profile to use:

[image]

- If you still get an error after that, probably you will need to download the
  provision profile from the web via Xcode settings -> accounts ->
  double click on your developer account -> click on download all button
  (bottom left)
- If still not working, your device UDID is probably not included in
  your provision profile, you will have to add it via apple member
  center website.

Answer (score 0):

If XCode can't fix the problem for you here are the manual steps.

1. Import your Developer AppleID profile to XCode (or just sign in your AppleID)
2. Create and download your iOS development certificate

   > 1) Go to developer.apple.com > Certificates, Identities & Profiles > iOS Certificates
   >
   > 2) Create new certificate if one doesn't exist (follow the instructions on the web site - You need the KeyChain application on your Mac to create intermediate certification)
   >
   > 3) Download your developer certificate
   >
   > 4) Import the certificate to XCode
3. Ensure you have created an App ID for your application

   > 1) Go to App IDs
   >
   > 2) Create an App ID (if does not exist)
4. Create and download App specific Provisioning Profile (Development is enough at this point)

   > 1) Go to Provisioning Profiles
   >
   > 2) Create iOS App provisioning profile (and bind your certificates)
   >
   > - Choose the Application ID you created in step-3
   > - Choose the developer certificate you created in step-2
   > - Choose your registered devices you want to use while testing
   > - Give name for your profile
   >
   > 3) Download the created profile
   >
   > 4) Double click should automatically open XCode and set the profile to your project (Just make sure your project settings includes the correct bundle identifier - The same you checked/created in step-3).

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows where you should change the setting.

1. if you just want to develop, you can set to the automatic.
2. If you are going to distribute. Make sure that you have a provisioning profile and choose it.

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4oYT.png)